# Is there a way to use c.* in CosmosDB?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm trying to run a query in CosmosDB but I can't seem to get the result the way I want it.

This is the query:

```
SELECT c FROM c
JOIN p in c.Data.packages 
WHERE p.packageId ="ID_9DACF11F-31F1-45C0-9A99-7ED846F9226E"
```

Is there a way to get the following result without the "c":

```
[
    {
        "c": {
            "id": "ID-6A23-432D-B862-4342D6B8C6F0",
            "prop1": "value",
            "prop2": "value",
            "Data": {
                "date": "2020-01-30T18:21:57",
                "packages": [
                    {
                        "packageId": "123"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
```

As in just:

```
[
    
        {
            "id": "ID-6A23-432D-B862-4342D6B8C6F0",
            "prop1": "value",
            "prop2": "value",
            "Data": {
                "date": "2020-01-30T18:21:57",
                "packages": [
                    {
                        "packageId": "123"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    
]
```

I know I can use c.id, c.prop1, etc. But I have tons of more properties, and it will get really hard to maintain in the future. So is there a way to achieve this?

Basically looking for something like this:

```
SELECT c.* FROM c
JOIN p in c.Data.packages 
WHERE p.packageId ="ID_9DACF11F-31F1-45C0-9A99-7ED846F9226E"
```

But this doesn't work obviously. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried * instead, docs says it will work. https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-getting-started

Comment: @Bjorne I get an error message: "'SELECT *' is only valid with a single input set."

Comment: Try VALUE c instead

Comment: Awesome, it works! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Bjorne Could you pls post your idea as an answer? Thank you a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For queries with multiple aliases use `VALUE c` instead.

```
SELECT VALUE c FROM c
JOIN p in c.Data.packages 
WHERE p.packageId ="ID_9DACF11F-31F1-45C0-9A99-7ED846F9226E"
```

Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-select